# Devise authenticate helper to redirect to a different log in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Normally, when a controller action requires authentication due to the authenticate_user! before filter, the user gets redirected to /users/sign_in.

Is it possible to redirect the user to a different log in page? One that I build, it's my own controller and action for just displaying the forms. It's called log_in_or_register so you can imagine what it does.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you set a different page on authentication failure:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

Answer (score 1):

Does the wiki article help?

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

Comment: Nope, that allows you to have a different URL map to the usual Devise action for logging in. I have a different action to display the log in form and I want authenticate_user! to redirect to it instead of redirecting to /users/sign_in.